# TinyMce: Saving img as path instead of Base64 to database

Tags: php, mysql, base64, tinymce

I'm writing my website articles using TinyMce, but the img source is saved in the database like this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4fPIRXhp..."/>
```

How do i save the path to the file instead? Like this:

```
<img src="myproject/images/picture1.jpg"/>
```

I'm sending the articles to the database using this PHP code:

**articles.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['btnViagens_país'])) {

$id_país = $_POST['id_país'];
$thumbnail = $_POST['thumbnail'];
$article = $_POST['article'];
$title = $_POST['title'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO country_page_journeys(countryPage_id, thumbnail, article, title) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('isss', $id_país, $thumbnail, $article, $title);
$stmt->execute();

if(!$stmt) {
    echo "Failed to execute: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
}    
$stmt->close();
}
```

Here is the code for TinyMce init:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
tinymce.init({   
relative_urls : false, 
images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
images_upload_base_path: '',
selector: "textarea",
theme: "modern",
height: 500,
width: 800,
paste_data_images: true,
plugins: [
  "advlist autolink lists link image imagetools charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
  "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
  "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
  "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
],
toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
image_advtab: true,
file_picker_types: 'image',
file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

input.onchange = function() {
  var file = this.files[0];

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function () {
    // Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
    // registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
    // necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
    var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
    var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
    var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
    var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
    blobCache.add(blobInfo);

    // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
    cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
  };
};
  input.click();
}
  });     
});
```

And the PHP handler:

```
<?php
  $accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.1", 
  "http://example.com");


 $imageFolder = "viagens_header_images";

 reset ($_FILES);
 $temp = current($_FILES);
 if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
   if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {

  if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
  } else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 403 Origin Denied");
    return;
  }
}

// Sanitize input
if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Invalid file name.");
    return;
}

// Verify extension
if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), 
array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Invalid extension.");
    return;
}

// Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
$filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

// Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
// Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
// { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
echo json_encode(array('location' => $filetowrite));
} else {
// Notify editor that the upload failed
header("HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error");
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this page from the TinyMCE documentation:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

The basic process is that TinyMCE will create a separate HTTP POST for each image that you insert into the editor. It will send that image to a URL of your choosing (via HTTP POST) based on the setting of the `images_upload_url` option in your TinyMCE configuration.

The image handler at the URL referenced in the `images_upload_url` (which you have to create) has to do whatever needs to be done to "store" the image in your application. That could mean something like:

- Store the item in a folder on your web server
- Store the item in a database
- Store the item in an asset management system

...regardless of where you choose to store the image your image handler needs to return a single line of JSON telling TinyMCE the new location of the image. As referenced in the TinyMCE documentation this might look like:

`{ location : '/uploaded/image/path/image.png' }`

TinyMCE will then update the image's `src` attribute to the value you return. If you use the `images_upload_base_path` setting in the init that will be prepended to the returned location.

The net here is that TinyMCE knows when an embedded image exists in your content but it can't possibly know what to do with that image in the context of your application so that job (the "image handler") is something you must create.

Comment: I've updated my question. I tried to use the image_upload_handler and the PHP upload handler but it's still storing the image as Base64 encoding. I'm not very experienced setting this up.

Comment: Is the image upload happening? What is your upload handler doing?  What is the handler returning?  What is the end result in the HTML?  Is there a reason you are using your own images_upload_handler as opposed to the one TinyMCE provides by default?  Until you know where in this process things are broken nobody will be able to help you fix it.

Comment: I am fairly certain that trying to write the file (in PHP) to anything with `http://` is not working.  Is `move_uploaded_file` failing?  What error is it providing?

Comment: Dear Michael. Thank you for being helpful. I tested the results in the article page and the HTML is retrieving the data just like it was stored in the database,like this: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR...The img tag doesn't even close which makes the HTML a mess. The reason i want to insert the path to the image in the database was because my browser was crashing everytime i submited an image since it was about 2MB. I decreased its size and it finally allowed me to insert it. I'll have several images per article so it's better to insert the path instead of encoding to Base64.

Comment: By the way, data is truncated in the database, as the article column is set as TEXT and it may not hold all the data i'm inserting. That was another reason i wanted the path to be set.

Comment: The fundamental issue you need to address is configuring TinyMCE to upload the images when they are first added - via `images_upload_url `.  There should not be Base64 encoded content when the form is finally submitted if you have TinyMCE setup to upload them when first created.

Comment: An update: Took away the image_upload_handler function, moved the images folder to the root of my CMS where i'm uploading the images and inserting them to the database and changed the $imageFolder variable path to the name of the image folder, like i wrote in the updated code on the 1st post. Now the Img src is returning "/BackOffice/viagens_header_imagesblobid1502980586698.jpg" and it displays neatly in my website. Hard to figure it out at first but it is yet another thing i learned. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If this is fixed can you accept the answer so others know this is resolved?

Comment: Dear @Michael. I have to ask your help again: Whenever i try to upload an image to the TinyMce editor, the page refreshes automatically and doesn't allow me to write my articles. Can you advise what to look for? Btw, the images are being saved in the root of my project instead of inside the folder where i defined in the postAcceptor.php.

Comment: The link above is broken, anyone wanting to see how to upload images should look here.
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/